# Is a composition of a Lipschitz continuous function with a Continuously Differentiable function Lipschitz over an unbounded set?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Assume the following:

- $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is a closed and connected set (not necessarily bounded),
- $\Xi \in Lip_{\alpha}(U,X)$, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$,
- $g \in C^1(X,Y)$, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{Y}^m$.

Is the function $G = g \circ \Xi: U \rightarrow Y$ Lipschitz?

Up to now, I cannot find neither a way to prove it true, nor a counterexample to prove it wrong. The problem is that: $\Xi(U)$ is not necessarily bounded, so I cannot assume $g$ Lipschitz on $X$, even if $g \in C^1(X)$. If $g$ would be Lipschitz, then the problem is trivial.

Comment: What about if the Lipschitz map is the identity map, and $g(x) = ||x||^2$? 
Is the composition Lipschitz?

Comment: Mmm I think this is a good counterexample, I did not think about the identity map as Lipschitz function!